# python memory exception when not at full memory usage

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using Ubuntu 64bit 12.04. My machine has 64gigs of RAM. I am running a script where I have to store ~9gig of data into a dictionary.

It is a simple dictionary where keys are 30 characters and value is just a integer.

However, the script is throwing a memory exception at around 58% memory usage. What is going on here? Is there a max limit to dictionary size?

Comment: 64 gigs of ram? That's overkill... But still, the memory usage seem's strange. Could there be something else that's running?

Comment: Are you doing any operation? Have you stripped your code only for storing those data?

Comment: @Zizou212
I work in genomics. It requires a lot of ram. There is something else running, but its only 4% of the ram.

Comment: @taesu
Yeah the code pretty much just loads the dictionary and then streams through another file. The exception is coming up during the dictionary loading.

Comment: Genomics sounds cool. Is there a sole python process or is it split into other threads and processes?

Comment: is it absolutely required that you load the file at once and be ready to go at any given time? or are you doing operation on the data as you go?

Comment: where does the data  come from ? Are you using utf-8 strings or plain ascii ? how many keys do you store in the dictionary? Are you aware that storing raw data into a dictionary takes more memory than the raw data ?, so it probably takes more than 9 gigs Do you know what an hashtable is ? Perhaps use something else other than dictionary ?

Comment: @WalleCyril: do _you_ know what a hashtable is?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a max value that limits the size of a dictionary in Python. Assuming your script is running under Unix, you can increase the memory limit your process can consume via standard library module [resource](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html).

```
>>> import resource
>>> resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (10**9, 10**9))
```

You may also want to periodically check the memory usage with `resource.getrusage()` function. The resulting object has the attribute `ru_maxrss`, which gives total memory usage for the calling process.

```
>>> import resource
>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
>>> 20631552
```

By this way, at least you can make sure that it is your script which eats the memory.